# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions in hibernate 4

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using JTA transaction manager in hibernate 4.Does anyone has any idea about the issue. While executing flush I am facing the error.

Below is the Piece of code where i am facing the above issue.

```
public void saveOrUpdateEvent(Event event)
{
 event = DomainReferenceMapper.map(event);
    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(event);
    session.flush();
```

XML:

```
 <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <!-- prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop-->

             <!-- Package was changed in the updgration of hibernate -->

            <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.TreeCacheProvider</prop>
            <!-- prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop -->
             <!--
             Added for hibernate upgradation
             -->
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>

        <!--<prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop> 
            --><prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

Comment: From the error, seems like your `event` object is from another session, one different from that returned at `Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();`.

Comment: @acdcjunior The method called is in different class so it means new transaction will be available am I right? If not can you please let me know how can i resolve

Comment: Why have you disabled second level cache? Also, if you are sure that object does not exist in DB, then use save, and if it does, then use session.merge(objectname); Please seperate the methods.

Comment: I didn't disabled the second level cache. I tried merge but when I perform other operation I'm not getting any response

Comment: what the method DomainReferenceMapper do ?

Answer (score -1):

```
public void saveOrUpdateEvent(Event event)
{
    event = DomainReferenceMapper.map(event);
    Session session = null ; 
    Transaction tran = null;
    try {
        session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();        
        tran =  session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(event);
        session.flush();
        tran.commit();
    } catch(Exception ex ) {
        ex.printstacktrance(); 
    }
```

Comment: Yupp, swallowing exceptions fixes almost every bug. At least long enough to find a new job if you are quick.

Comment: it was not a complet code , just to presente the idea behide it